# How to convert Iterable[Try[U]] filter successed to Iterable[U]?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I tried

```
val tryValues : Iterable[Try[Int]] = ...
val successValues = tryValues.filter(_.isSuccess).map(_.get)
```

but compiler give warning that map may throw exception.
Is there any way free of warning?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option here, if you don't care to log anything about the fails is to `flatMap` using `toOption` on the `Try`.  Like so:

```
val successValues = tryValues.flatMap(_.toOption)
```

Comment: I think yours is more elegant and can be used on spark RDD, too.

Comment: @Renkai You can use `collect` with an `RDD` the same way. It also makes it clear that you're collecting successes.

Answer (score 8):

You want to use `collect` to pattern match out all the values which are `Success`, and discard anything else.

```
val successValues: List[Int] = tryValues collect { case Success(x) => x }
```

`collect` accepts a `PartialFunction` as an argument. Any values from the collection that the `PartialFunction` is defined for will be mapped, and the rest will be discarded.

Example:

```
scala> val tryValues = List(1, 1, 0, 1, 1).map(x => Try(1 / x)) 
tryValues: List[scala.util.Try[Int]] = List(Success(1), Success(1), Failure(java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero), Success(1), Success(1))

scala> val successValues = tryValues collect { case Success(x) => x }
successValues: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is a for-comprehension approach

```
val successValues = for { Success(n) <- tryValues } yield(p)
```

For more information have a look at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61763561/for-comprehension-yield-raises-type-mismatch-compiler-error/61763615#61763615)