# for-comprehension yield raises type mismatch compiler error

Tags: scala, compiler-errors, yield, type-mismatch, for-comprehension

I want to extract from `Iterable[Try[Int]]` a list of all valid values (`Iterable[Int]`)

```
val test = List(
    Try(8), 
    Try(throw new RuntimeException("foo")), 
    Try(42), 
    Try(throw new RuntimeException("bar"))
)
```

The following is the way to print all valid values from `test`:

```
for {
    n <- test
    p <- n
} println(p)

// Output
// 8
// 42
```

However, when I tried to save the valid values to list I have received an error:

```
val nums: Seq[Int] = for {
    n <- list
    p <- n    // Type mismatch. Required: IterableOnce[Int], found Try[Int]
} yield(p)
println(nums)
```

How to fix the error and why it was raised?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try collect

```
test.collect { case Success(value) => value }
// res0: List[Int] = List(8, 42)
```

In a for-comprehension format that corresponds to

```
for { Success(p) <- test } yield p
```

Both make use of [Constructor Patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.13/08-pattern-matching.html#constructor-patterns) which under the hood perform `isInstanceOf` type test followed by `asInstanceOf` type cast. Verbosly that corresponds to something like

```
test
  .filter (_.isInstanceOf[Success[Int]])
  .map    (_.asInstanceOf[Success[Int]].value)
```

The following for-comprehension does not work because the monads in it have to align

```
for {
  n <- test  // List monad
  p <- n     // does not align with Try monad
} yield (p)
```

The above for-comprehension desugars to

```
test.flatMap((n: Try[Int]) => n.map((p: Int) => p))
```

and looking at the signature of `flatMap` we see it expects a function

```
Try[Int] => IterableOnce[Int]
```

whilst we provide

```
Try[Int] => Try[Int]
```

because `n.map((p: Int) => p)` returns `Try[Int]`. Now the following for-comprehension is a whole different beast

```
for {
    n <- test
    p <- n
} println(p)
```

because of the absence of `yield` it desugars to

```
test.foreach((n: Try[Int]) => n.foreach((p: Int) => println(p)))
```

where `foreach` expects a function of type

```
Try[Int] => Unit
```

which we indeed provide because `n.foreach((p: Int) => println(p))` indeed returns `Unit`.

Answer (score 3):

You can also try:

```
val nums: Seq[Int] = list.map(_.toOption).flatten
```

or

```
val nums: Seq[Int] = list.flatMap(_.toOption)
```